# Can I call a function by clicking 'OK' in messagebox.showinfo?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have added a message box in my code and I want to call a function defined earlier when clicking the 'OK' button in the message box. Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

```
messagebox.showinfo('Correct', 'Correct!\nClick OK to continue')
```

Comment: Just call the function after `showinfo` returns. In case there is more than one button (e.g. for `askokcancel`), check the result first. Or do you want the (possibly long-running) function to start and complete _before_ the message dialog disappears?

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks mate. that did it.. thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a showinfo box, it actually halts your script until you press OK.  All you will need to do is put the function you want right after it.

See this example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def go():
    messagebox.showinfo('Correct', 'Correct!\nClick OK to continue')
    print('yeah')

root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root, text='click', command=go)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If you run that, you will see the `print('yeah')` only happens when the user clicks OK.  So, you can do something similar and call the function where I have put the print.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Didn't know it was this simple. (complete python newbie btw, if you can't tell already)…. again thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and looked for a simple code. You can use:

```
from tkinter import Tk,messagebox

root=Tk() 
result=messagebox.showinfo('Correct','Correct!')
root.destroy()
go()
```

I used root.destroy() because sometimes I had problems closing the popup window.

In tkinter.messagebox.showinfo your only option is to press OK or close the tkinter popup window, both has the same effect and returns a string "ok".

If you instead want to call a function only when you press yes use tkinter.messagebox.askyesno:

```
from tkinter import Tk,messagebox

root=Tk() 
result=messagebox.askyesno('Correct','Correct!')
root.destroy()
if result==True:
    go()
```